# Error in build on device Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-activity, phonegap-build

I want to run my app on my real device Android but I receive this error:

```
Running command: D:\WebStorm\Path\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device '02c5cabed02456d5'. Running: D:\WebStorm\Path\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D: \WebStorm\Path\platforms\android\build.gradle
-PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg. gradle.daemon=true Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException : Connection refused: connect
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketI mpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja va:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket Impl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java :188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC onnection.java:1168)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConn ection.java:1104)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne ction.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection .java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo nnection.java:1512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon nection.java:1440)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more

D:\WebStorm\Path\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "D:\WebStorm\Path\platfo rms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\WebStorm\Path\platforms\android \build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true" ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: D:\WebStorm\Path\pla tforms\android\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8 You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I installed the Android sdk and I added to my Path in Windows7 this:

```
C:\Development\android-sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Development\android-sdk\tools;
C:\Development\android-sdk\android-sdk
```

Where is the problem???

Answer (score 16):

It is seems be issue with proxy only.
You can set proxy in two ways.

1. Create/Edit `gradle.properties` @ `c:\Users\<username>\.gradle\`

> `OR`

2. Goto your project location and do the same as above

> Example : `platforms/android/gradle.properities`

3. Write below content in file

> ```
> systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxyhost
> systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
> systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
> systemProp.http.proxyPassword=pwd
> systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
> systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyhost
> systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
> systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
> systemProp.https.proxyPassword=pwd
> systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
> ```

Comment: It worked for me. Also noticed username and pwd fields are mandatory, even if proxy doesn't actually require authentication.

Answer (score 5):

This link helped me: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/proxy-error-when-downloading-gradle-zip-during-ionic-emulate-android/31701

To find `.gradle`, go to your user folder (default is `c:\Users\<your login>`). In case `gradle.properties` is not existing, simply create one

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your stacktrace it seems to be some kind of connectivity problem. Is your computer is using any proxy to connect to network? if yes then that have to be configured for your build tool as well. As i can see it is just trying to download **gradle-2.2.1-all.zip** and it is failing due to connection problem.

**Solution:** Steps to configure proxy in nodejs

npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Hope that information helps you.

Regards
Himanshu

Comment: I use the proxy...How can I configure it?

Comment: @user3751473 Looking at the log files I guess you are using **nodejs** to build it. So the instruction on how to configure proxy for your nodejs installation is on this [link](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/).

Comment: Does it comes with username/password for company proxy or is it direct??

Comment: I set with username/password

Comment: What i came accross [this](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/) forum that if your password contains '@' character npm have trouble parsing the string. In that case use it as : http://"user:P@ssword"@proxy.server:1234

Comment: I configured accurately the proxy but I have the same problem

Comment: I guess then you need to talk to your IT service people to get it resolved. It sounds more like a network issue.