# Ionic gradle build Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, build.gradle

I get the following error when I build the ionic app using script 'ionic build android --prod --release'

```js
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Develop\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1.1-all.zip




Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more
```

It worked 2 days ago, but fails after I reinstall my system.
I'm wasting too many hours to solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in build on device Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001328/error-in-build-on-device-android)

Comment: I fixed the problem.

Comment: The problem was because I set JAVA_HOME variable to jre folder.